# pg_dump Crashing PostgreSQL Server

Tags: postgresql

Running pg_dump on a database containing a large number of blobs, when this query gets executed PostgreSQL crashes:

```
pg_dump: reading large objects
pg_dump: error: query failed: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
pg_dump: error: query was: SELECT l.oid, (SELECT rolname FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles WHERE oid = l.lomowner) AS rolname, (SELECT pg_catalog.array_agg(acl ORDER BY row_n) FROM (SELECT acl, row_n FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(l.lomacl,pg_catalog.acldefault('L',l.lomowner))) WITH ORDINALITY AS perm(acl,row_n) WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(pip.initprivs,pg_catalog.acldefault('L',l.lomowner))) AS init(init_acl) WHERE acl = init_acl)) as foo) AS lomacl, (SELECT pg_catalog.array_agg(acl ORDER BY row_n) FROM (SELECT acl, row_n FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(pip.initprivs,pg_catalog.acldefault('L',l.lomowner))) WITH ORDINALITY AS initp(acl,row_n) WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(l.lomacl,pg_catalog.acldefault('L',l.lomowner))) AS permp(orig_acl) WHERE acl = orig_acl)) as foo) AS rlomacl, NULL AS initlomacl, NULL AS initrlomacl FROM pg_largeobject_metadata l LEFT JOIN pg_init_privs pip ON (l.oid = pip.objoid AND pip.classoid = 'pg_largeobject'::regclass AND pip.objsubid = 0)
```

I've experimented with the query and the two `array_agg()` columns for **lomacl** and **rlomacl** seem to be the culprit.

It's AWS Aurora PostgreSQL 11:

```
SELECT version();
                                             version
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PostgreSQL 11.9 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 7.4.0, 64-bit
```

Logs:

```
2021-08-19 19:47:46 UTC::@:[46753]:LOG: server process (PID 21837) was terminated by signal 9: Killed
2021-08-19 19:47:46 UTC::@:[46753]:DETAIL: Failed process was running: SELECT l.oid, (SELECT rolname FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles WHERE oid = l.lomowner) AS rolname, (SELECT pg_catalog.array_agg(acl ORDER BY row_n) FROM (SELECT acl, row_n FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(l.lomacl,pg_catalog.acldefault('L',l.lomowner))) WITH ORDINALITY AS perm(acl,row_n) WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(pip.initprivs,pg_catalog.acldefault('L',l.lomowner))) AS init(init_acl) WHERE acl = init_acl)) as foo) AS lomacl, (SELECT pg_catalog.array_agg(acl ORDER BY row_n) FROM (SELECT acl, row_n FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(pip.initprivs,pg_catalog.acldefault('L',l.lomowner))) WITH ORDINALITY AS initp(acl,row_n) WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.unnest(coalesce(l.lomacl,pg_catalog.acldefault('L',l.lomowner))) AS permp(orig_acl) WHERE acl = orig_acl)) as foo) AS rlomacl, NULL AS initlomacl, NULL AS initrlomacl FROM pg_largeobject_metadata l LEFT JOIN pg_init_privs pip ON (l.oid = pip.objoid AND pip.classoid = 'pg_largeobject'::regclass AND pip.objsubid = 0)
2021-08-19 19:47:46 UTC::@:[46753]:LOG: terminating any other active server processes
2021-08-19 19:47:46 UTC::@:[46753]:FATAL: Can't handle storage runtime process crash
2021-08-19 19:47:46 UTC::@:[46753]:LOG: database system is shut down
```

Any troubleshooting steps/suggesstions?

Comment: What is your exact Postgres version (`select version()` will tell  you) and which operating system are you using?

Comment: `signal 9: Killed` seems to indicate it crashed badly?

Comment: Probably killed by the OOM killer.  Look in /var/log/kern.log

Comment: Try the `pg_dump` with `--no-blobs` to not dump them, just to confirm they are the issue.

Comment: Yup, did a dump without blobs and no issues there.

Comment: So are the blobs in a single or subset of tables? Also how what is their total size?

Answer (score 2):

`pg_dump` uses this join between `pg_largeobject_metadata` and `pg_init_privs` to get a list of large object OIDs to dump.

Now either the memory on the database server is so low, or you have got many large objects and your `work_mem` is set very high, so that the database server machine runs out of memory. Since you didn't disable memory overcommit on the database server operating system, the OOM killer kills your process.

Either increase the available RAM or use a more conservative `work_mem` setting. I have to add that bevore v13, PostgreSQL was prone to mistakenly create hashes that were bigger than `work_mem`. Perhaps you could set `enable_hashjoin` to `off` for the duration of the dump.

Comment: This is running on a db.r5.12xlarge instance(48 vCPU/384GB RAM) and I've tried setting work_mem anywhere between 4MB - 16GB.  I'll take a look at that hashjoin setting, thanks!

I'm also currently running a vacuumlo, that's removing +25 million orphaned large objects.

Comment: That will certainly help. There are many problems with large objects, particularly if you have many of them.